# Navigate a React App link to Express server dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, npm, mern

I am trying to navigate a front end link on React JS app to an Express server.

**Example**

```
<a href="/pages">Pages</a>
```

In the Express server, I wrote this piece of code

```
app.get('/pages', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Pages');
});
```

I have also updated my front end package.json file like so:

```
"proxy": {
   "/pages" : {
      "target" : "http://localhost:5000"
   }
}
```

My React App is running on port 3000 and Express server is running on port 5000. However, when I click on the link **Pages** nothing happens. I have to explicitly change the front end link like so to make it work:

```
<a href="http://localhost:5000/pages">Pages</a>
```

Is there any way how I could dynamically connect my React App with my Express server without having to specify `http://localhost:5000` in all the links everytime?

Comment: make express server serve frontend on the same port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!
My package.json wasn't updated because of hot reloading. I had to kill the existing webpack server and run it again to make it work.
In future, if anyone is stuck around with this situation, simply make sure you update your **package.json** file like so:

```
"proxy": {
   "/pathname" : {
       "target" : "http://yourserveraddress"
   }
 }
```

Comment: This no longer seems to work as `"proxy"` only accepts a string, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be

```
"proxy": {
  "/pages" : {
    "target" : "http://localhost",
    "port" : 5000
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives this error: Proxy error: Could not proxy request /page from localhost:3000 to http://localhost/ (ECONNREFUSED).

Comment: I thought you solved your problem? Otherwise try to also set changeOrigin: true to allow cors.

Comment: Yes, it is solved. I just mentioned that this answer gave me the  response I mentioned.